# RMST2 covariates do not produce confidence intervals

Tags: r, survival-analysis, survival

I am using the rmst2 package on R. When i run the model without covariates, I get this result:

```
Restricted Mean Survival Time (RMST) by arm 
               Est.    se lower .95 upper .95
RMST (arm=1)  9.788 0.279     9.241    10.334
RMST (arm=0) 10.433 0.396     9.657    11.210


Restricted Mean Time Lost (RMTL) by arm 
              Est.    se lower .95 upper .95
RMTL (arm=1) 2.022 0.279     1.476     2.569
RMTL (arm=0) 1.377 0.396     0.600     2.153


Between-group contrast 
                       Est. lower .95 upper .95     p
RMST (arm=1)-(arm=0) -0.646    -1.595     0.303 0.182
RMST (arm=1)/(arm=0)  0.938     0.855     1.030 0.178
RMTL (arm=1)/(arm=0)  1.469     0.786     2.745 0.228
```

When I add covariates to this, I get the following output:

```
Summary of between-group contrast (adjusted for the covariates) 
                       Est. lower .95 upper .95  p
RMST (arm=1)-(arm=0) -0.541        NA        NA NA
RMST (arm=1)/(arm=0)  0.950        NA        NA NA
RMTL (arm=1)/(arm=0)  1.420        NA        NA NA
```

I have looked at the time, status, and arm variables and cannot find anything missing. Similarly, when looking at the covariates, there are no gaps in data. I tried using different tau cut-offs to see if it would help, but that did not work. Thoughts?

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Surely one of the example datasets in the ‘survival’ or ‘rmst2’ packages could be used in an example? Otherwise this question will probably be closed as lacking sufficient detail for reproduction.